# SQL Find Records in Another Table Based (Using Like?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been unsuccessfully trying to get this to work for the past 2 days and hope I can find someone who can help.

One table contains major events and the other contains minor events based on the major in the other table.   For example Table1 contains ID, DATE and NUMBER (along with several other columns). These records are numbered consecutively numbered for each ID and each day.

Table2 contains the minor events if the items in the first table have one or more.  It uses the same information but adds the SEQ column and NARR column (among others).  There can be multiple entries for the one entry in the table below.

[image]

I am trying to find a way to search for every event in table1 that does not have at least 1 record in table2 to that contains a word; in this example “widget”.  Basically, based on the examples above, I would be returned (I struck through the record that would not be returned).

[image]

So items that had no minor event or had minor events but nothing that said “widget” would be displayed. There can be over a hundred minor records for each major.  All I want it to do is tell me if there isn’t 1 minor record in that hundred that doesn’t say “widget” or if it has no minor records.

I hope this all makes sense.  Please let me know if there are any questions.  Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `not exists`.  Something like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.number = t1.number and
                        t2.narr like '%widget%'
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.number = t1.number 
                 );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response.  I think that is giving me all the records that don't exist in table2.  Which is great (I am still going through it now) but I don't see any that have records in table2 but they don't have a record that contains the word "widget"

Comment: Looks like that worked.  Thanks so much for your assistance.  This was kicking my butt.  You are a hero!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Not IN:

```
Select * 
from table1 t1 
where t1.number not in(select number from Table2 t2 where narr like'%widget%')
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that would not return items that had entries in Table2 but did not have at least one entry for "widget".

Comment: @JamesBenton If I understand it correctly, I believe it does. This shows everything in Table1 except those numbers that have '%widget%' in Table2.